# Cannot log in to Windows 10 after deleting profile in registry

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles, regedit

So I ended deleting my only profile through registry thinking it would fix *"The update could not be completed undoing changes problem"*.

Now I cannot even log in my account. I tried resetting my password through the `Windows Live Account Settings` but it did not work.

Please help, I have a recovery disk but  I can't do much from there. I can access the command prompt however.

Comment: Enable the built-in Administrator account, delete your now broken profile, and create a new User profile

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have made a mistake.
Deleting your only profile is risky. If I were you, if you want your computer back, run the Windows Repair/Recovery disc that came with the computer. Go to BIOS and set it to boot from your CD Drive: this will bring you to a menu where you can either try to repair Windows , or completely re-install it.